# What is an algebra "minus" a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I'm trying to understand the proof of the *Frobenius's Theorem*: "If $A$ is an algebraic division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ we get $A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H}$"

The case $\dim A=1$ is trivial. In case $\dim A\geq 2$ the proof takes $x \in A \setminus \mathbb{R}$. Now my question is, what is $A \setminus \mathbb{R}$? It has dimension $1$?

Thank you all!

Comment: You mean like $\Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R$? This is not even a vector space, since $0$ is not contained in  it. What do you mean by "dimension" then?

Comment: he means $A\setminus  \mathbb{R}$ as $A$ is an extension, and yes it is no vs but still nonempty. So it just means all the elements in $A$ that are not in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Enkidu Possibly, but it would be better "he" would clarify the question himself. The question about the notation $A\setminus B$ is a duplicate, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2403052/what-can-be-understood-by-a-b-b-a-in-set-theory).

Comment: If $A$ is an algebra, $A \setminus \mathbb{R}$ is the same that remove the subalgebra $\mathbb{R}1$ from $A$, no?